# nginx rewrite error issue

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

my request url is : 
  http://localhost/swim/api/v1/member/xx

the nginx error log msg is:

```
2015/06/30 18:58:57 [error] 42780#0: *9 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/swim/api/v1/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/i    ndex.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/member/xx", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /swim/api/v1/memb    er/xx HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost
```

nginx.conf rewrite rule is:

```
    location ~ ^/swim/api/(.*) {
      if ($uri ~* "/swim/api/v(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)$") {
          set $ver $1;
          set $con $2;
      }
      rewrite ^/swim/api/(.*)$ /swim/api/v$ver/index.php/$con last;
  }
```

Comment: And what did you expected if rewritten uri still matches this location?

Comment: i will the rules match something like this:                      
localhost/swim/api/v1/member/xx 
localhost/swim/api/v2/param1/param2 
localhost/swim/api/v1/param3/param4/param4/paramN
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a **higher priority** location configured that will match the re-written url.

E.g:

```
location ~ ^/swim/api/v(\d+)/index.php/(\d+).* {
  echo 'Hello $2' ;
  #proxy pass to your real upstream server here
}

location ~ ^/swim/api/v(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)$ {
  set $ver $1;
  set $con $2;
  rewrite ^/swim/api/(.*)$ /swim/api/v$ver/index.php/$con last;
}
```

> curl http://127.0.0.1/swim/api/v10/007/bond

Output:

> Hello 007